# Show that $\mathbb{E}[T_A\mid Z_0=k] = \sum_{\ell\in S} \mathbb{E}[T_A \mathbb{1}_{\{Z_1 = \ell\}}\mid Z_0=k].$

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

I am reading [Notes on Markov Chain](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/nprivault/MAS328/MAS328-5.pdf).

Consider a Markov chain $(Z_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ with state space $S$ and let $A\subseteq S.$
Define 
$$T_A = \inf\{n\geq 0: Z_n\in A\}.$$
Mean hitting time is defined by 
$$h_A(k) = \mathbb{E}[T_A\mid Z_0 = k].$$
At page $152,$ the author stated the following.

> $$\mathbb{E}[T_A\mid Z_0=k] = \sum_{\ell\in S} \mathbb{E}[T_A \mathbb{1}_{\{Z_1 = \ell\}} \mid Z_0=k].$$

I do not understand why the equality holds. 
I think it is due to the law of total expectation, but I am not sure how it is applied here. 
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is the law of total expectation. Note that $\displaystyle \sum_{l \in S} 1_{\{Z_1 = l\}} = 1$.

Comment: For every integrable random variable $X$, partition $(A_n)$ and event of positive probability $B$, $$X=\sum_nX\mathbf 1_{A_n}$$ hence $$E(X\mid B)=E\left(\sum_nX\mathbf 1_{A_n}{\Large\mid} B\right)=\sum_nE(X\mathbf 1_{A_n}\mid B)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
E_k T_A = E_k \left(T_A \sum_{\ell \in S} \textbf{1}_{\{Z_1 = \ell\}}\right) = \sum_{\ell \in S}E_k T_A \textbf{1}_{\{Z_1 = \ell\}},
\end{align*}
where $E_k$ is shorthand for expectation with respect to the probability measure on strings starting with $X_0 = k$.